# jne not jumping? (assembly x86 NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cmp

For some reason my cmp statement here always causes a `je` to `DoubleScore`, and never `jne` to the `RegularScore` function. I am fairly new to assembly so it is probably a simple mistake.

```
  Approved:
                        mov eax,[prev]
                        mov edi,  dword[buffermaze+eax]
                        mov eax,edi
                        call print_nl
                        call print_int
                        mov eax, 45
                        call print_nl
                        call print_int

                        cmp eax,edi
                        je DoubleScore
                        dump_regs 1
                        jne RegularScore
                        dump_regs 2

                                DoubleScore:
                                        mov ebx,0
                                        ret
                                RegularScore:

                                        mov edx, 0
                                        mov eax,[new]

                                            ret


The Output for this part of the code is 
774778411
45
Register Dump # 1
EAX = 0000002D EBX = F7704FF4 ECX = 00000000 EDX = 00000000
ESI = 0804A434 EDI = 2E2E2E2B EBP = FFF2D4E8 ESP = FFF2D4C4
EIP = 080487B0 FLAGS = 0283       SF          CF
```

Comment: Show code for print_nl + print_int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the code fragment

```
 call print_nl 
 call print_int
```

those two functions might do something to the registers eax and edi. Have you tried debugging the code ?

Edit:
`jne RegularScore` refers to DumpRegs2, not the `cmp eax, edi`

in my opinion  it should be like this:

```
                cmp eax,edi
                je DoubleScore
                dump_regs 1
                ;here we will handle the regularScore


                                mov edx, 0
                                mov eax,[new]

                                    ret


                        DoubleScore:
                                mov ebx,0
                                ret
```

Comment: I tested it, removed the code fragment. And the values stay the same. I really don't have a clue, they are obviously not equal so why on earth would it think they are?

Comment: @user3043234 honestly, this is the only option. Have you tried removing 4 lines of calling and not just 2?

Comment: @user3043234 I think the problem is somewhere else. your other jumping instruction `jne RegularScore` refers to DumpRegs2, not the `cmp eax, edi`

Comment: Removing the dump regs has no effect, it just outputs all the registers and their values, i tried removing it and nothing happens. I have quite a bit of other code in this program, but none that i know of should interfere. I have plenty of other jumps and they are all working fine.  Even if i blatantly put 1 in edi, and 5 in eax, and compare them it still jumps equal

Comment: yes but I meant removing the `jne RegularScore` part since the order in your program is first you compare 2 registers (it sets the flags) then you jump (it ALSO sets the flags after jumping) - and then there should be part of the code where you handle regularscore, without jumping.

Comment: I think i may have found the error somewhere else in my code, i did not think anything else interfered with that function but it did. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

would this work;

```
    cmp eax,edi
    je DoubleScore // if equal jmps to DoubleScore and jmps back to passedNotEqual
    jmp RegularScore // if je fails, jmps to RegularScore and returns normal
passedNotEqual:

        DoubleScore:
                mov ebx,0
                dump_regs 1
                jmp passedNotEqual

        RegularScore:

                mov edx, 0
                mov eax,[new]
                dump_regs 2
                ret
```